# HTML5 elements only stretch to size of window

Tags: css, html

I am putting together a HTML5 page. I notice that divs without specified widths within elements such as "header" and "footer" only fill the width of the window. So, if for example you have:

```
<header>
   <div id="header-background" style="background: #ddd">
      <h1 style="width:960px">Hello World</h1>
   </div>
</header>
```

And you reduce the size of the window to below 960px (e.g. 600px) and scroll horizontally, the "header-background" will only stretch to 600px, and to the right will be a white space.

You can see this in action even at stackoverflow.com

Is there a way around this?

Comment: What does this have to do with HTML5, or HTML in general for that matter? Stack Overflow doesn't even use those new semantic elements.

Comment: "can see this in action at stackoverflow.com" What action? SO has a fixed width layout – there is no fluid layout. "Is there a way around this?" Around what? I don't get what your question is…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any block level element will take up 100% of the page width by default. If you have a width that you can't ( or don't want to ) go under, then you can use `min-width`

```
header { 
    min-width: 960px;
    width: auto; 
}
```